# High protein intake at a time

Tags: strength-training, protein, supplements, nutrition-information, high-protein

I am aware of that per kg protein intake and all.

AFA my routine is concerned, I workout in the evening (around 8 - 9.30 p.m).

Before workout, I take 1 scoop of protein (25gm protein) and after workout 1 scoop.

Along with a scoop of protein after workout, I also take 2 boiled eggs (10gm protein) and a glass of milk (mixed with protein, around 8gm protein) + whatever I get from my dinner.

So, this all counts around 70gm of protein in a time span of around 1.5 - 2 hours.

I read somewhere that its of no use to take more amount of protein at a time.

Is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea that there is a certain amount of protein a person can absorb with in a set period of time is false according to this [article](http://www.t-nation.com/diet-fat-loss/protein-will-not-make-you-fat).

In short, the author points out that if it is true that we can only absorb 30g of protein in one sitting, as is widely accepted to be true by many, we would all be excreting the excess amount of food undigested. Since that is not the case, it is pretty clear that your body can absorb all the protein you eat in one siting.

Comment: That article looks promising. Thanks for the answer.